# What is the JS equivalent of the files param in the python requests library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have an api that is used to upload files through a post endpoint. This is how I successfully do this in python:

```
    files = {
        'payload': (None, json.dumps(payload), 'application/json'),
        'file': (file_name, open(full_path, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
    }

    r = requests.post(f'{url}upload/', files=files)
```

I need a way to make this exact same request using axios in JS.

I have unsuccessfully tried the following:

1. form-data package
2. formdata-node package
3. axios-form-data package

Using the axios-form-data package I attempt to send a request like this:

```
async uploadFile(form_data, file_part) {
  axios.interceptors.request.use(axiosFormData);
      return await axios.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `${url}`upload/',
        data: {
          payload: 'Non-file value',
          file: fs.readFileSync("test/helpers/resources/test.csv", "utf-8");
        }
      });
}
```

Each time, with each library, my api endpoint is hit, but with an empty request.form object (api is built with Flask in python)

What am I doing wrong when trying to send this request?

Also, this is set to `type: module` in my package.json file, so I can't use CommonJS packages.

Edit:
Changed axios-form-data function to this, still unsuccessful:

```
async uploadFile(form_data, file_path) {
  axios.interceptors.request.use(axiosFormData);
      return await axios.request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `${url}`upload/',
        data: {
          payload: 'Non-file value',
          file: fs.createReadStream(file_path);
        }
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> `fs.readFileSync("test/helpers/resources/test.csv", "utf-8")`

The return value of `readFileSync` is a string.

`axios-form-data` only works when it detects a *file*.

Use `createReadStream` (also from the `fs` module) as per [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-form-data).

Comment: Updated to this but still getting an empty request form:
```
  async uploadFile(form_data, file_path) {
    axios.interceptors.request.use(axiosFormData);
    return await axios.request({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${url}upload/`,
      data: {
        payload: 'Non-file value',
        file: fs.createReadStream(file_path),
      }
    });
  }
```